# JAVA_HOME "bug"

Tags: java, android, python, c++

so I trying to build project for cocos2d-x. I'm currently at cmd and when I type `python android-build.py -p 19 cpp-tests` it start making project but then I get error that build failed. Problem is bescause it can't find javac compiler.

> "Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDk. It is currently set to
>   "c:/Program Files/Java/jre7"

Problem is bescause in system variables I made new variable called JAVA_HOME and it is pointed to `C:\android\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin` but still I getting that error. What to do guys?

Comment: Have you restarted your computer sense you made the variable?

Comment: ug_ Yes I did. Still same "It is currently set to "c:/Program Files/Java/jre7" i don't understund how is that possible..

Comment: Make sure that there isnt a user variable overriding it.

Comment: I tried to find and there is no variable that have c:/Program Files/Java/jre7 location :/

Comment: What do you see when you execute `echo %JAVA_HOME%`?

Comment: Also JAVA_HOME generally points to JDK dir and not the bin dir inside it. SO JDK_HOME should point to `C:\android\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`.

Comment: I see C:/android/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin I will remove that bin but I still don't think that is problem

Comment: I encountered this error as well. I have my echo %JAVA_HOME% pointing to the JDK but it still says it is pointing to JRE7.

Answer (score 0):

You have to point JAVA_HOME to this path:

> C:\android\Java\jdk1.8.0_05